# Autolayout debug build differs from release build

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have a containerview that holds a UITableview.  With the debug build everything looks good-

[image: Debug build]

But with the release build the childviewcontroller appears inset-

[image: Release build]

Here is the storyboard for the containerview-
[image]

And here is the code instantiating the view-

```
self.dailyWeatherTableViewController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DailyForecastViewController"];
self.dailyWeatherTableViewController.view.frame =self.view.frame;
UIEdgeInsets newSafeArea;
newSafeArea.top=self.headerView.frame.size.height;
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.dailyWeatherTableViewController.additionalSafeAreaInsets=newSafeArea;
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
[self addChildViewController:self.dailyWeatherTableViewController];
[self.forecastContainerView addSubview:self.dailyWeatherTableViewController.view];
[self.dailyWeatherTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The view hierarchy debugger shows that the UITableviewCellContentView has an encapsulated-layout width set to 261.  Some googling seems to reveal that this relates to the view's autoresizingmask but changing this or setting the view's frame in the cellforindex method does not fix it.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the tableview constraints-

[image]

Comment: What elements are not sizing correctly?  Give your views varying background colors, so you can clearly see the frames for the elements.

Comment: I did some digging with the view hierarchy debugger and it looks like the culprit may be the cell's contentview but I can't figure out how to fix it.  See the question edits above.

Comment: Tough to tell... I assume you're not getting any auto-layout warnings / errors? It's possible (likely?) that the `encapsulated-layout width` is being set/enforced by the tableView's width... How does the tableView itself look (in Debug View Hierarchy)?

Comment: Also you say "here is the code instantiating the view" but where? You do realize that `viewDidLoad` would be absolutely the wrong place to do that???? Unless you _also_ provide autoresizing or autolayout but you seem to be doing neither.

Comment: @DonMag the uitableviewcontroller and cell appear to be full with at 375 but the contentview is 261.

Comment: @matt the code was in viewDidLoad but changing it to viewWillAppear gives the same result.

Comment: I found the fix- adding newSafeArea.right=0 and newSafeArea.left=0 allowed the contentView to use the entire width.  I am not sure why this was necessary but it did fix problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the culprit was the additionalSafeAreaInsets of the container.  After adding 0 for left and right, the margins were fixed-

```
`if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UIEdgeInsets newSafeArea;
    newSafeArea.top=self.headerView.bounds.size.height;
    newSafeArea.right=0;
    newSafeArea.left=0;
    newSafeArea.bottom=0;
    self.dailyWeatherTableViewController.additionalSafeAreaInsets=newSafeArea;
}`
```

I'm still not sure why this was necessary as the apple example does not do this- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area?language=objc